# Unable to download the groovy eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, groovy, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

Unfortunately I am not able to download the groovy eclipse plugin via the URL http://dist.springsource.org/snapshot/GRECLIPSE/e4.5/. The download will be executed without error but the file downloaded has always 0 Bytes as result. The name of the file downloaded is e4 or very cryptic. It occurrs on different accounts, with different providers and different PCs.

Answer (score 0):

That is an eclipse update site. I guess you are trying to put that URL in the browser. They are not supposed to be used in the browser, but rather through eclipse.

Open eclipse, go to `Help > Install New Software...` and paste that URL in the `Work with:` field.

More info update sites can be found [here](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-127.htm).